# Binning/averaging data in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm currently trying to solve this; I have an idea of how to do this, but I would really appreciate any extra input I could get.

I need to come up with a Binning function that takes in raw thickness data from a trace file, that is read in by  another function. **I need to put this data in 5mm bins**. The tricky part will be to smooth fit the curves at both ends, and also perform data validation of the input data.

In summary: I need to take data values and "bin"/average them in 5mm intervals.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the [`hist()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) function, which creates a histogram by binning the input data.

Comment: will the hist() function allow me to set the 5mm intervals? I trying to get a continuous curve.

Comment: @GianP: Indeed.  If you take a look at the documentation I linked to, there are ways to set either the number of bins, or the bin centres.